# Redirect different users to different screens in flutter after firebase authentication

Tags: flutter, dart, firebase-authentication

I am creating an application where different users should be redirected to different pages. If its **xyz@xyz.com**, he should be redirected to SpecialUserHome and all other users should be redirected to UserHome. I am new to flutter can anyone help me how to do this? Here is my mapping.dart

```
class MappingPage extends StatefulWidget {
  final AuthImplementation auth;

  MappingPage({
    this.auth,
  });
  State<StatefulWidget> createState() {
    return _MappingPageState();
  }
}

enum AuthStatus {
  notSignedIn,
  signedIn,
}
class _MappingPageState extends State<MappingPage> {
  AuthStatus authStatus = AuthStatus.notSignedIn;
  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
      widget.auth.getCurrentUser().then((firebaseUserId) {
      setState(() {
        authStatus = firebaseUserId == null
            ? AuthStatus.notSignedIn
            : AuthStatus.signedIn;
      });
    });
  }


  void _signedIn() {
    setState(() {
        authStatus = AuthStatus.signedIn;
    });
  }

  void _signOut() {
    setState(() {
      authStatus = AuthStatus.notSignedIn;
    });
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    switch (authStatus) {
      case AuthStatus.notSignedIn:
        return LoginRegisterPage(
          auth: widget.auth,
          onSignedIn: _signedIn,
        );

      case AuthStatus.signedIn:
        return UserHome(
          auth: widget.auth,
          onSignedOut: _signOut,
        );
    }
    return null;
  }
}
```

And my login.dart

```
class LoginPage extends StatefulWidget {
  LoginPage({
    this.auth,
    this.onSignedIn,
  });
  final AuthImplementation auth;
  final VoidCallback onSignedIn;
  State<StatefulWidget> createState() {
    return _LoginState();
  }
}

enum FormType { login, register }

class _LoginState extends State<LoginPage> {

  final formKey = GlobalKey<FormState>();
  FormType _formType = FormType.login;
  String _email = '';
  String _password = '';


  //methods
  bool validateAndSave() {
    final form = formKey.currentState;
    if (form.validate()) {
      form.save();
      return true;
    } else {
      return false;
    }
  }

  void validateAndSubmit() async {
    if (validateAndSave()) {
      try {
        if (_formType == FormType.login) {
          String userId = await widget.auth.signIn(_email, _password);
          dialogBox.information(
              context, 'Congratulations!', 'You logged in successfully');
          print('Login user id =' + userId);
        } else {
          String userId = await widget.auth.signUp(_username,_email, _mobile, _password);
          dialogBox.information(context, 'Congratulations!',
              'Your account has been created successfully');
          print('Register user id =' + userId);
        }
        widget.onSignedIn();
      } catch (e) {
        print(e.toString());
      }
    }
  }



  void moveToLogin() {
    formKey.currentState.reset();
    setState(() {
      _formType = FormType.login;
    });
  }

  //Design
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: Container(
        margin: EdgeInsets.all(15.0),
        child: Form(
          key: formKey,
            child: ListView(
              children: <Widget>[
                 child: Column(crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.stretch,
                  children: createInputs() + createButtons(),
                ),
              ),
            ],
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }

  List<Widget> createInputs() {
    return [
      TextFormField(
        validator: (value) {
          return value.isEmpty ? 'please provide email' : null;
        },
        onSaved: (value) {
          return _email = value;
        },
      ),
        obscureText: true,
        validator: (value) {
          return value.isEmpty ? 'password is required!' : null;
        },
        onSaved: (value) {
          return _password = value;
        },
      ),
    ];
  }

  List<Widget> createButtons() {
    if (_formType == FormType.login) {
      return [
        RaisedButton(
          child: Text('Login'),
          onPressed: validateAndSubmit,
        ),
      ];
    } 
  }
}
```

Comment: You should look at `provider` plugin for flutter. https://pub.dev/packages/provider Here is an excellent tutorial on YouTube on how to implement user authentication login using firebase in flutter. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=sfA3NWDBPZ4&list=PL4cUxeGkcC9j--TKIdkb3ISfRbJeJYQwC